# For n odd, skew symmetrical matrices in $M(n,\mathbb{R})$ are homeomorphic to orthogonal matrices for which $\det(A+I) \neq 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices

I have a continuous mapping $A \mapsto (A-I)(A+I)^{-1}$ between the set of orthogonal matrices $A^{t}A=I$ s.t. $\det(A+I) \neq 0$ and the set of skew symmetrical matrices $A^{t}=-A$ in $M(n, \mathbb{R})$ with $n$ odd, so that $\det(A)=0$. How to prove it’s a homeomorphism? By artificially creating an inverse? By noting that the domain is open and proving that the image is so too, and then...?

Answer (score 0):

If $B = (A-I)(A+I)^{-1}$, then $A = (I+B)(I-B)^{-1}$.